# Specifying CMake options for external CMake project

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'd like to use the following to wrap a CMake-native project in a catkin environment by exporting the build_type as cmake:

(Code preview on GitHub issue: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/1007)

While this works great to build, it defaults all options as in the CMake project. In many cases, we'd like to set a few of those - e.g., not to build tests etc. (what we would usually do by cmake .. -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF). Is there a way to do this, or a convenient work-around?

Thanks,
Wolfgang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322231/specifying-cmake-options-for-external-cmake-project/) by [wxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/41136/wxm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you build your workspace with [colcon](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/) you can put a [colcon.pkg](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/configuration.html#colcon-pkg-files) file beside the manifest to specify custom `cmake-args` just for that package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2019-04-30**:
So you can specify this in the source of the package and you can customize the defaults for that package (compared to a non-colcon build just using cmake) when built with colcon, which is great. But is there a way to change the options per-package when building / configuring a workspace? I.e. having some options in one workspace, and another set in another workspace, without changing the package source, just by different colcon commands / workspace-wide config.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2019-04-30**:
Wait, I think I misunderstood how the .meta files work. It should be possible with those (either with name or path).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-04-30**:
The difference of a `colcon.pkg` file is that it can be co-located with the package in source - rather than `.meta` / `.mixin` files which are usually outside the workspace and might need to be referenced explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you building your workspace with `catkin_tools`, you can specify cmake args (`--cmake-args` I believe), but the caveat is that they are passed to all packages.

Another approach that gives you more control is to wrap your plane cmake package into a catkin package, e.g. using ExternalProject. Here is an example: https://github.com/uzh-rpg/pangolin_catkin

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2019-04-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/41136/wxm/) on 2019-04-30**:
Thank you very much for the answer - I am currently using `ExternalProject` but wanted to see whether I can directly pass option on a *per-package* level in catkin (it's likely a feature request for catkin). My use case is exactly as yours - I am packaging a package as a catkin wrapper and use `ExternalProject`. the `--cmake-args` options sets it workspace-wide, which is not what I want, given that I intend to bloom-release the package where I do not have this liberty.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2019-04-30**:
Doesn't bloom allow you to include "patch files" that can tweak the defaults of options in the CMakeLists.txt as needed?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-04-30**:
There are two parts to `catkin`: the CMake functions provided (the build system part) and the scripts `catkin_make(_isolated)` which invokes CMake on a set of packages (the build tool part). This kind of functionality you are looking for is in the build tool part. `catkin_tools` is a separate package providing a better build tool (though it is not actively maintained). Another build tool is `colcon` which was developed for ROS 2 (and non-ROS projects, also works for ROS 1).

**Comment by [wxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/41136/wxm/) on 2019-04-30**:
Good call! While this is an option for bloom, that wouldn't work out of the box for someone building the package in the workspace, I presume (unless I rebase the patch for the workspace repository)?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2019-04-30**:
Wait, if you use ExternalProject, you can specify any options you want in the wrapper project, no? Or are you asking how to replace it and not have a wrapper project? How would you get the package.xml (or colcon.pkg) file in the package root?

**Comment by [wxm](https://answers.ros.org/users/41136/wxm/) on 2019-04-30**:
@demmeln: Correct, I am currently using ExternalProject but due to some shortcomings with the generation of pkg-config files in catkin (and downstream may use pkg-config rather than `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)`), I need to manually export a `CFG_EXTRAS` to set the equivalent variables - which is error-prone. I have the chance to get the `package.xml` upstream-ed into the project so it would build fine in a workspace as a cmake-buildtype-project. However, some extra CMake options need to be set by the user and do not auto-configure - that's why I asked. With ExternalProject, I directly pass them in.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2019-05-02**:
Makes sense. So I guess the answer is, its possible with colcon, e.g. with a colcon.pkg file (instead of package.xml) in the upstream repo, but as of now not with catkin_tools.